# iOS: Multiple intersecting views

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiview

I am making a day view calendar just like the native iPhone calendar. I am trying to position the tiles the same as in the native calendar, side by side, if they are the same size and same time.

However, I can only figure out how to do it to 2 tiles and not multiple tiles. In the attached image I have 4 tiles. One that expands slightly into the other 3. I then have the first tile on the far left and the second tile just after the first one. Now I need to figure out how to add the additional tiles?

How would I do this for more than 2 tiles?

About the image: If you can't see it the 3rd tile is ontop of the 2nd tile (you can see it is a bit darker since they are on top of each other.

[image: screenshot]

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Set the main
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        APCalendarDayTile *tile = (APCalendarDayTile *)view;
        CGFloat startPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.startDate]];
        CGFloat endPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.endDate]];
        tile.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftSideBuffer, startPos, (self.bounds.size.width - kLeftSideBuffer) , endPos - startPos);
        tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:tile.appointment.appointmentColor];
    }

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        APCalendarDayTile *tile = (APCalendarDayTile *)view;

        if ([self viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:tile]) {

        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:(UIView*)selectedView{
    NSArray *subViewsInView=[self subviews];// I assume self is a subclass
    // of UIViewController but the view can be
    //any UIView that'd act as a container 
    //for all other views.
    for (UIView *theView in subViewsInView){
        if (![selectedView isEqual:theView]) {
            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selectedView.frame, theView.frame)) {
                if ((selectedView.frame.origin.y == theView.frame.origin.y) && (selectedView.frame.size.height == theView.frame.size.height)) {
                    if (theView.frame.size.width == self.bounds.size.width - kLeftSideBuffer) {
                        theView.frame = CGRectMake(theView.frame.origin.x, selectedView.frame.origin.y, theView.frame.size.width / 2, selectedView.frame.size.height);
                    }
                    selectedView.frame = CGRectMake(theView.frame.origin.x + theView.frame.size.width, selectedView.frame.origin.y, theView.frame.size.width, selectedView.frame.size.height);
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I sorta took SaltyMule's approach however, his pseudo code didn't make sense in the if / else.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Set the main
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        APCalendarDayTile *tile = (APCalendarDayTile *)view;
        CGFloat startPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.startDate]];
        CGFloat endPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.endDate]];
        tile.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftSideBuffer, startPos, (self.bounds.size.width - kLeftSideBuffer) , endPos - startPos);
        tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:tile.appointment.appointmentColor];
    }

    [sameTimeAppointments removeAllObjects];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        APCalendarDayTile *tile = (APCalendarDayTile *)view;

        if ([self viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:tile]) {
            if ([sameTimeAppointments objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tile.frame.origin.y]] != nil) {
                NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[sameTimeAppointments objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tile.frame.origin.y]] mutableCopy];
                [tempArray addObject:tile];
                [sameTimeAppointments setValue:tempArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tile.frame.origin.y]];
            } else {
                [sameTimeAppointments setValue:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:tile] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tile.frame.origin.y]];
            }
        }
    }
    for (NSString *currentDict in sameTimeAppointments) {
        NSArray *currentAppointments = [sameTimeAppointments objectForKey:currentDict];
        float tileWidth = ((self.frame.size.width - kLeftSideBuffer) / [currentAppointments count]);
        for (int i = 0; i < [currentAppointments count]; i++) {
            APCalendarDayTile *tile = [currentAppointments objectAtIndex:i];
            float xPos = 0.0 + kLeftSideBuffer;
            if (i != 0) {
                xPos = (((APCalendarDayTile *)[currentAppointments objectAtIndex:i - 1]).frame.origin.x + tileWidth);
            }

            tile.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, tile.frame.origin.y, tileWidth, tile.frame.size.height);
            [self bringSubviewToFront:tile];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:(UIView*)selectedView{
    NSArray *subViewsInView=[self subviews];// I assume self is a subclass
    // of UIViewController but the view can be
    //any UIView that'd act as a container 
    //for all other views.
    for (UIView *theView in subViewsInView){
        if (![selectedView isEqual:theView]) {
            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selectedView.frame, theView.frame)) {
                if ((selectedView.frame.origin.y == theView.frame.origin.y) && (selectedView.frame.size.height == theView.frame.size.height)) {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your test

```
if ((selectedView.frame.origin.y == theView.frame.origin.y) && (selectedView.frame.size.height == theView.frame.size.height))
```

Is only applied to views of equal y origin and height. I would solve this problem using the following pseudo code:

```
initialize an empty arranged subviews array
initialize a nil previous subview
for every subview
    if the subview intersects with the previous subview
        ensure the subview and the previous subview are added to the arranged subviews array
    else if the arranged subviews array is not empty
        arrange the subviews in the array across the width of their superview
        empty the arranged subview array
```

Comment: No I have it right. I only want ones that start at the same time and go the same length to be side by side

Comment: Your if/else seems to be a bit confusing.